# Cannot order IBM Cloud virtual servers with suspended billing

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, virtual-server

I got the error about the newly introduced service.

Ref. Virtual servers now with suspended billing and 1-minute granularity - IBM Cloud Blog : https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2018/06/virtual-servers-suspended-billing/

```
Item C1_1X1X25 does not exist for package SUSPEND_CLOUD_SERVER
```

It does not seem to have any preset id.
The actual command is as follows.

```
slcli order place --verify SUSPEND_CLOUD_SERVER TOKYO \
--complex-type SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest\
--preset C1_1X1X25 \
GUEST_CORE_1 \
RAM_1_GB \
REBOOT_REMOTE_CONSOLE \
100_MBPS_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINK \
BANDWIDTH_0_GB \
1_IP_ADDRESS \
GUEST_DISK_25_GB_SAN \
OS_CENTOS_6_X_MINIMAL_64_BIT_2 \
MONITORING_HOST_PING \
NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET \
AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION \
UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT \
NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING \
--extras '{"virtualGuests": [{"hostname": "suspendable", "domain": "ibmcloud.com"}]}' 

slcli order preset-list SUSPEND_CLOUD_SERVER
:......:.........:.............:
: name : keyName : description :
:......:.........:.............:
:......:.........:.............:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new feature, there were some issues but it seems that this devices can be ordered now.

```
slcli order preset-list SUSPEND_CLOUD_SERVER
:..............:..............:..............:
:     name     :   keyName    : description  :
:..............:..............:..............:
: B1.16x32x100 : B1_16X32X100 : B1.16x32x100 :
:  B1.1x4x100  :  B1_1X4X100  :  B1.1x4x100  :
: B1.16x64x100 : B1_16X64X100 : B1.16x64x100 :
:  B1.2x8x100  :  B1_2X8X100  :  B1.2x8x100  :
:  B1.1x2x25   :  B1_1X2X25   :  B1.1x2x25   :
:  B1.1x4x25   :  B1_1X4X25   :  B1.1x4x25   :
:  B1.2x4x25   :  B1_2X4X25   :  B1.2x4x25   :
: B1.16x32x25  : B1_16X32X25  : B1.16x32x25  :
: B1.16x64x25  : B1_16X64X25  : B1.16x64x25  :
:  B1.1x2x100  :  B1_1X2X100  :  B1.1X2X100  :
:  B1.2x4x100  :  B1_2X4X100  :  B1.2x4x100  :
:..............:..............:..............:
```

Try with the following command:

```
$ slcli order place --verify SUSPEND_CLOUD_SERVER TOKYO \
--complex-type SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest \
--preset B1_1X2X25 \
REBOOT_REMOTE_CONSOLE \
100_MBPS_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINK \
BANDWIDTH_0_GB_2 \
1_IP_ADDRESS \
OS_CENTOS_6_X_MINIMAL_64_BIT_2 \
MONITORING_HOST_PING \
NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET \
AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION \
UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT \
NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING \
--extras '{"virtualGuests": [{"hostname": "suspendable", "domain": "ibmcloud.com"}]}'
```

Comment: The following commands are needed before going to order command.

    ```sudo easy_install nose```
    ```sudo easy_install tornado```
    ```pip install --upgrade pip```
    ```pip install --upgrade Softlayer```